# Flutter: Fade in a non network image

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter but loving it.  I am trying to make a simple splash screen where the logo fades in, however, all the examples I find seem to be around network assets.

I have looked at FadeInImage, and ImageFade

```
class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand( // -> 01
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/background/splash_background.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,    // -> 02
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork (image:'assets/icons/echofide_complete.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [AnimatedOpacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedOpacity-class.html) would suffice because your using an asset image.

Comment: I did do this, and found I needed to do a hack for the visibility to work